# Parsing json array in array swift

Tags: arrays, json, swift

Got the following `JSON`! I’m trying to get a single url from those tree inside images array! Can anyone please explain me how I can get it.

```
let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
    do {
        let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(
                with: data!,
                options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers
        ) as! [String: AnyObject]
        if let artists = json?["artists"] as? [String: AnyObject] {
            if let items = artists["items"] {
                for i in 0..<items.count {
                    let item = items[i] as? [String: AnyObject]
                    let name = item?["name"] as! String
                    self.nameArray.append(name)
                    let popularity = item?["popularity"] as! Int
                    self.popuArray.append(popularity)
                    if let artists = item["artists"] as? String: AnyObject {
                        if let images = artists["images"] as? [String: AnyObject] {
                            let imageData = images[0]
                        }
                    }
                    print(name)
                    print(popularity)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am able to get the values from name and popularity.
No way for this url… inside images!
My json is a spotify.. api

Looks like this:

```
{
  "artists": {
    "href": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?query=Metallica&type=artist&market=CA&offset=0&limit=20",
    "items": [
      {
        "external_urls": {
          "spotify": "https://open.spotify.com/artist/2ye2Wgw4gimLv2eAKyk1NB"
        },
        "followers": {
          "href": null,
          "total": 3455148
        },
        "genres": [
          "alternative metal",
          "alternative rock",
          "hard rock",
          "metal",
          "rock",
          "speed metal",
          "thrash metal"
        ],
        "href": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/2ye2Wgw4gimLv2eAKyk1NB",
        "id": "2ye2Wgw4gimLv2eAKyk1NB",
        "images": [
          {
            "height": 640,
            "url": "https://i.scdn.co/image/5a06711d7fc48d5e0e3f9a3274ffed3f0af1bd91",
            "width": 640
          },
          {
            "height": 320,
            "url": "https://i.scdn.co/image/0c22030833eb55c14013bb36eb6a429328868c29",
            "width": 320
          },
          {
            "height": 160,
            "url": "https://i.scdn.co/image/c1fb4d88de092b5617e649bd4c406b5cab7d3ddd",
            "width": 160
          }
        ],
        "name": "Metallica",
        "popularity": 83,
        "type": "artist",
        "uri": "spotify:artist:2ye2Wgw4gimLv2eAKyk1NB"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I want to pick any url i want from those 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears you just need to update this line..

```
if let images = artists["images"] as? [String: AnyObject] {
```

to

```
if let images = artists["images"] as? [[String: AnyObject]] {
    if let firstImage = images.first, let urlString = firstImage["url"] as? String {
         let url = URL(string: urlString)  
    }
}
```

`[String:AnyObject]` casts to a Dictionary object, `[[String:AnyObject]]` casts to an Array of Dictionary objects which is what you need in this case